# Milk container on shabbos 

Tags: shabbat, food

Can you open a milk container on shabbos? also what about those Orange Juie containers that have the straw can you stick them in on shabbos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are those that hold you may not. See this link for a lengthy discussion of the issues.

http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1620

Comment: he essential statement: Even though it is a partial answer: Rav Moshe rules that one may not open a milk or juice carton on Shabbos since this creates a spout (Shu’t Igros Moshe, Orach Chayim 4:78

Comment: I was yold rabbi Yackov Kamentetzky disagreed can anyone confirm or deny?